# Making black pixels transparent

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, pixel

I have two images and they have the same size. Now I need to remove pixels in Image 1 which is color black in btmp

```
for (int c = 0; c < selFrame.Width; c++)
  for (int j = 0; j < selFrame.Height; j++)
    {

     var pixel = selFrame.GetPixel(c, j);
     var pixel2 = btmp.GetPixel(c, j);
     if (pixel2.Equals(Color.Black) || pixel2.IsEmpty)
       {
       MessageBox.Show("qwe");
       selFrame.SetPixel(c, j, Color.Transparent);
       }

    }
```

MessageBox doesn't show, so that means that it didn't go through the If condition.

Here is the btmp

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [255,0,0,0] does *not* equal `Color.Black`.

From the [documentation:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e03x8ct2(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1)

> For example, Black and FromArgb(0,0,0) are not considered equal, since Black is a named color and FromArgb(0,0,0) is not.

As per the advice at the above documentation, change your check to be :

```
if (pixel2.ToArgb() == Color.Black.ToArgb() || pixel2.IsEmpty)
```